# Javascript: How can I add the values of an object that belong to a shared key?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object containing states and their balances.

```
    {
      "amount": "822370.71",
      "state": "ME"
    },
    {
      "amount": "968817.53",
      "state": "FL"
    },
    {
      "amount": "587603.26",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "FL"
    }
```

How could I add the amounts that belong to each state, for example OH would have 587603.26 + 657617.83. I believe the map() method is to be used here but I am not sure how to go about using it. Thanks!

Comment: What structure the bunch of objects you presented is incorporated in? An array?

Comment: @zerkms correct

Comment: So, make it explicit. Then - implement what you want with a good old `for` loop.

Comment: @zerkms Heh I would, but this is component of an assignment and so I must use functional js to solve it

Comment: Seems like [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a better candidate than *map*.

Comment: Well, you don't get to "functional" instantly, first make it any way, then "improve". Learning is an iterative process.

Comment: @RobG I think that could be, but I need to have a total amount for each state, won't reduce just leave me with one value?

Comment: @zerkms I agree, but it is required we use functional to solve this. We have already gone deep into imperative

Comment: *"won't reduce just leave me with one value?"* - You can code it so that the one "value" is actually an object or array containing the consolidated data with one total per state.

Comment: `input.reduce((acc, {amount, state}) => ({...acc, [state]: (acc[state] || 0 + parseFloat(amount))}), {})` --- very functional, such es6, wow

Comment: There are several [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672816/javascript-object-sum-value-based-on-properties-effeicently) [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects) besides the one I linked to when I closed the question.

Comment: @ColinSygiel—yes, but that value can be an object, array, whatever. It would have helped greatly if you'd provided sample output (and your attempt at an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short solution using `Array.prototype.forEach()` function:

```js
var arr = [{"amount": "822370.71","state": "ME"},{"amount": "968817.53","state": "FL"},{"amount": "587603.26","state": "OH"},{"amount": "657617.83","state": "OH"},{"amount": "657617.83","state": "FL"}],
    result = {};

arr.forEach(function (o) {
    var amount = Number(o.amount);
    (result[o.state])? result[o.state] += amount : result[o.state] = amount;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case for `filter`, `map` and `reduce` used together.

```js
let input = [{
  "amount": "822370.71",
  "state": "ME"
},
{
  "amount": "968817.53",
  "state": "FL"
},
{
  "amount": "587603.26",
  "state": "OH"
},
{
  "amount": "657617.83",
  "state": "OH"
},
{
  "amount": "657617.83",
  "state": "FL"
}];

let map = input
  // Create a map from each state to all its entries
  .reduce((all, a) => {
    all[a.state] = all[a.state] || [];
    all[a.state].push(a);
    return all;
  }, {});

for(let state in map) {
  map[state] = map[state]
    // Get the amount from each entry
    .map(a => a.amount)
    // Turn into a number
    .map(parseFloat)
    // Add each number in turn
    .reduce((acc, a) => a+acc, 0);
}

console.log(map);
```

Comment: I think `.map(a => a.amount)
  .map(parseFloat)` could be eliminated...

Comment: Thanks, however I need to be able to map these summed amounts for all common states, not just particular ones.

Comment: @ColinSygiel now are given an example, apply your new knowledge and solve your particular task!

Comment: @ColinSygiel I updated the answer